# How to extract only the text which is not inside any tag using xpath with selenium and python binding

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Link to the page is: "https://www.members.agta.org/assnfe/CompanySearch.asp?MODE=DETAIL&COID=1026706&COMPNAME=&CITYNAME=&STATENAME=&CITYID=0&STATEID=0&CTRYID=181&SEARCHIDENTIFIER=81.145.145.150_12/24/2019%203:31:24%20AM&RETAILMBRS=0&ORGTYPE=0&GEMSTONEID=-1&PRODUCTSID=-1&COMPANYDATA=&TID=2&GEMCOLORID=-1&GEMCUTID=-1&GEMQUALID=A"

Here is the html i am targeting:

```
<p><strong>Contact:</strong> 
Garmendia, Diane
<br>
<strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:Diane33jewels@gmail.com">Diane33jewels@gmail.com</a><br>
<strong>P:</strong> 805-957-9100<br>
<strong>F:</strong>   805-957-4191<br>
<a href="http://www.33jewels.com" target="_blank">http://www.33jewels.com</a>
<!-- <b>Email Link:</b> $MC:EMAILLINKTOFORM$ -->
</p>
```

I need to extract "Garmendia, Diane" using the xpath expression.

I have tried using:

```
cname=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Contact:')]//following-sibling::text()[1]")
```

But the error i am getting is:

```
Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[contains(text(), 'Contact:')]//following-sibling::text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Extract the `Garmendia, Diane` use `javascripts executor` and `childNodes`

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() with following `XPATH`

Code:

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//p[contains(.,'Contact:')]")))
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent;', element))
```

Comment: that works, can you please guide how can i get the P: (PHONE) as well ?

Comment: they can be at arbitrary positions, so can't use the childNodes[1].

Comment: This is way you should get it.To get the phone number you can try `print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[10].textContent;', element))`

Comment: The best way to get this using beatiful soup.If you wish I can post that answer as well.

Comment: its ok i know about the beautiful soup. !